# Graphics path minilanguage line aliasing

Tags: wpf, graphics, path

I am trying to draw a tick in a checkbox and for reason the aliasing doesn't seem to work, the lines are really jagged and don't look good at all. I am missing somthing?

```
<Style x:Key="{x:Type CheckBox}" TargetType="CheckBox">
    <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Black"/>
    <Setter Property="RenderOptions.EdgeMode" Value="Aliased"/>
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="CheckBox">
                <BulletDecorator Height="20" MinHeight="20">
                    <BulletDecorator.Bullet>
                        <Grid 
                              Width="20"
                              Height="20">
                            <Border x:Name="Border" 
                                    CornerRadius="0" 
                                    Background="Black"
                                    BorderThickness="0"
                                    BorderBrush="Black"
                              Width="20"
                              Height="20" >
                                        <Path 
                                        x:Name="CheckMark"
                                        Stroke="White"
                                        StrokeThickness="8"
                                        Data="M 3,8 L 5,17,17,2"/>
                            </Border>
                        </Grid>
                    </BulletDecorator.Bullet>
                    <ContentPresenter Margin="0,0,0,0"
                            VerticalAlignment="Top"
                            HorizontalAlignment="Left"
                            RecognizesAccessKey="True" RenderOptions.EdgeMode="Aliased"/>
                </BulletDecorator>
                <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                    <Trigger Property="IsChecked" Value="false">
                        <Setter TargetName="CheckMark" Property="Visibility" Value="Collapsed"/>
                    </Trigger>
                </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

Comment: That `RenderOptions.EdgeMode="Aliased"` looks very suspicious... shouldn't be `"Antialiased"` or something?

Comment: Can't believe how much time I have wasted and all I had to do was to set render options to "unspecified".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Managed to fix this by setting the render options to unspecified.